# How to disable Spacemacs from auto-balancing the split windows?

Tags: spacemacs, window-splitting

I am using Spacemacs and after using the splitting windows feature, either by splitting horizontally or vertically, Spacemacs always try to balance the split windows.

For example, when pressing `C-x 3` twice, I expect something like this:

```
++++++++++++++++
|      |   |   |
|      |   |   | 
++++++++++++++++
```

But Spacemacs always produces this:

```
++++++++++++++++
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
++++++++++++++++
```

Do you know how to disable Spacemacs from doing so?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spacemacs sets `window-combination-resize` to `t`, which causes Emacs to split windows evenly. You need to add this to `user-config`:

```lisp
(setq window-combination-resize nil)
```

Comment: Thank so much for your answer! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: interestingly, this is the default value in vanilla emacs. That explains why I never had this issue in emacs.

Comment: If I eval the code manually it works, but not if I put it in my configuration. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The [golden-ratio](https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio.el) package does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but golden-ratio always shrinks other inactive windows. Is there any other solution instead of using golden-ratio?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the width of the windows in `golden-ratio` ? I'm not sure how(i dont use `golden-ratio` anymore), but there is a way to adjust so that it splits the windows to a certain ratio other than default. Check their github page for more info

Comment: Thanks for your clue. It's good to know about the option of `golden-ratio`